# Replacing an ADBannerView with custom image

Tags: objective-c, ios, iad

So I have an iOS app, and when there are no available ads to be displayed I want to display my own ad instead of hiding the banner. My custom ad is just an image, and when the user clicks on it I want to send him to an URL. What is the simplest way to do this that doesn't involve using another library like adWhirl? If it's not possible to place the image directly inside the banner, how would I scale the image to the banner size and place it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put your own image inside the iAd banner (which I think is your hope).

Make sure you DO hide the iAd banner when there are no ads.

Then add/remove your own ad view when appropriate - your own ad view could be as simple as a uiButton.

Answer (score 0):

In the `GoogleAdMobManager` class

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
```

Use this method.

Comment: I've implemented that, but how would I replace the ad with an image?

Comment: create a UIButton with adbanner size. and set image on uibutton. if adbanner is fail, you can unhide your UIButton..